# Android: Show events in a "timeline" each day

Tags: android, calendar

I am currently building an app which is supposed to have a calendar like fragment that shows active bookings for certain objects. I'm thinking this could be implemented in a listview where each row represents a specific day. Something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPzrK.png

However I have no idea how to implement the "timeline" or if it's even possible.
The bookings are retrieved from a MySQL-database and need to be inserted into the timeline colorcoded depending their "type".

Is it possbile to do this and if not are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

First,
It's possible
the simplest way i see for you is to draw rectangles inside your timeline paint them according to their type, and give them margin and size according to their start time and length. put the all inside a frame layout.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you care to elaborate, what do you meen by "draw rectangles inside timeline"? How, more precisely, can I implement this?

Comment: I'm not gonna wirte it for you. check the followinghttp://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html and try to implement it with frame layout as timeline that contains frame layouts as rects.